# Can some explain me how this solution works

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I solved the following problem by trial and error, and still have not proper understanding of how i did that.

There is a function cons :  `const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);`

Cons store value to a variable pair : `const pair = cons(5, 3);`

Create two functions car and cdr which each of them gonna return a argument of each.

`car(pair); // 5`

`cdr(pair); // 3`

My solution:

`const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);`

`const cdr = pair => pair((x, y) => y);`

```js
const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);

const pair = cons(5, 3);

const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);

const cdr = pair => pair((x, y) => y);

const carTest = car(pair);
const cdrTest = cdr(pair);

console.dir(carTest);
console.dir(cdrTest);
```

Comment: I sometimes find it helpful to rewrite the arrow functions as regular functions — it makes the closures and return values a little easier to understand (for me at least).

Comment: Did that. Still had problem with solving the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer how you "did it", since you seem to have stumbled over the answer.

Cheating a bit by inventing a thought process that is never so linear when you don't already know the answer, one way to approach it is to first look closely at what `cons` does:

```
const cons = (x, y) => (f => f(x, y))
```

It takes two things, `(x, y)`, and then returns a function.
This function takes another function `f` and returns the result of applying that function to the `(x, y)` that `cons` was given.

For `car`, we want to extract the first element of such a pair.

To select the first element of `(x, y)`, we can pass it to the function

```
const first = (x, y) => x
```

Since a pair is a thing that takes a function and applies that function to its elements, passing `first` to a pair should select its first element:

```
(cons(3,5))(first)
```

is 3.

But the syntax is now "backwards", so we use another function to turn it around:

```
const car = p => p(first)
```

Substituting the definition of `first`:

```
const car = p => p((x,y) => x)
```

The same process leads to `cdr`.

---

To see exactly what's happening, you have

```
const pair = cons(5, 3);
```

Substitute the definition of `cons`:

```
const pair = f => f(5, 3);
```

Apply `car` to `f => f(5,3)` and keep substituting:

```
(pair => pair((x, y) => x)) (f => f(5,3))

-->

(f => f(5,3)) ((x, y) => x))

--> 

((x, y) => x)) (5,3)

--> 5
```

Comment: The first part brought some enlightenment. Any idea where i can find similar excersices to practise?

Comment: I would recommend a dive into the lambda calculus. Interesting exercises could be representing the booleans as functions and implementing conditionals, or representing integers as functions (no language-level numbers allowed) and implementing addition.

Comment: so lisp/scheme basically? Or you mean something else? 
What about Haskell? I found more resources for Haskell, but i am ready to dive in whatever it takes in order to get better in FP

Comment: I literally meant the lambda calculus, but any of those should work. (I would recommend Racket, though. Lispy syntax, nice language, useful IDE, helpful community.)

Answer (score 2):

Here `cons(x, y)` constructs a `pair`, and `car(pair)` and `cdr(pair)` returns the `first` and `last` element of that `pair`.

And `pair` is also a `function` which takes  function as an input and returns the input function's output as `x` and `y`.

---

**For better explanation of your solution:**

```
const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);
```

**Rewrite the arrow functions as regular functions:**

```
function car(pair){

   var result= pair(
   function temp(x, y){
     return x;
    }
   );
   return result;
}
```

**Here**

**1.** **Car** function takes `pair` as `argument`.

> ***const car = pair***  =>..............;

**2.** `pair` is a `function` that takes another function as input which 2 `arguments` having 5 ,3 as `value`.

> ...............=>  ***pair(***......***)***;

**3.** These 2 `values` are passed as `argument` and assigned in `x, y` and `x` is returned as result.

> ..............(***(x, y) => x***);

---

```js
const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);

const pair = cons(5, 3);

//const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);
const cdr = pair => pair((x,y) => y);

function car(pair){
   
   var result= pair(
   function temp(x, y){
     return x;
    }
   );
   return result;
}
const carCall = car(pair);
const cdrCall = cdr(pair);

console.log(carCall);
console.log(cdrCall);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the types:

```js
// cons :: (a, b) -> ((a, b) -> r) -> r
const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);

// pair :: ((Number, Number) -> r) -> r
const pair = cons(5, 3);

// fst :: (a, b) -> a
const fst = (x, y) => x;

// snd :: (a, b) -> b
const snd = (x, y) => y;

// car :: (forall r. ((a, b) -> r) -> r) -> a
const car = pair => pair(fst);

// cdr :: (forall r. ((a, b) -> r) -> r) -> b
const cdr = pair => pair(snd);
```

As you can see, `cons` takes two values `x :: a` and `y :: b` and creates a pair. A pair is a function which takes *another* function as an input and returns the output of the *input function* by applying it to `x` and `y`. This allows us to do things like add values of the pair (i.e. `cons(5, 3)((x, y) => x + y)` which evaluates to `8`).

Now, if we apply the pair to the functions `fst` and `snd` then we get the first value and the second value of the pair respectively. Hence, `car` and `cdr` simply apply the input pair to the functions `fst` and `snd` respectively. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is that a Haskell based answer?

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: according to your profile you have knowledge in both Scheme and Haskell. Based on your opinion which would be more beneficial for a beginner javascript programmer in order to get good in FP?

Comment: Since you already know JavaScript, I'd say go with Haskell. Scheme is similar to JavaScript. Hence, you'd learn more about FP by learning Haskell than by learning Scheme. There's a great online book call Learn You A Haskell. You should read that.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cons = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);
const pair = cons(5, 3);
// pair = f => f(5, 3)
const car = pair => pair((x, y) => x);
// replace f as (x, y) => x
// then ((x, y) => x)(5, 3)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.